# To pass אעביר (Exo 33:19), what does it mean?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, moshe-rabbeinu, kavod, parashat-ki-tisa

Exodus 33:19 reads: " אני אעביר כל־טובי על־פניך ", I know it's often translated somewhat like [this](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0233.htm): "*I will make all My goodness pass before thee (before thy face)*", but I noticed it's root ע - ב - ר can also mean something like 'to transfer' or 'to pass something'. And because it states that it is על־פניך, I wondered if HaShem foretold Moshe here that He would cause 'His Goodness, His Kawod, Something of His Essence, His Light' to transfer upon or over his face. As Moshe asked HaShem to reveal his כבוד, and later on one reads that the face of Moshe shone (Exodus 34:29-30).

Any commentaries or explanations which explain אעביר in such manner?

P.s. I noticed the same word occures in Ezekiel 14:15 and Zechariah 13:2.

Answer (score 2):

The OP asked:

> I noticed it's root ע - ב - ר can also mean something like 'to transfer' or 'to pass something'. And because it states that it is על־פניך, I wondered if HaShem foretold Moshe here that He would cause 'His Goodness, His Kawod, Something of His Essence, His Light' to transfer upon or over his face. As Moshe asked HaShem to reveal his כבוד, and later on one reads that the face of Moshe shone (Exodus 34:29-30).
>
> Any commentaries or explanations which explain אעביר in such manner?

Yes! Rabbeinu Bachya/Bechaya suggests this here, in discussing why it says על פניך as opposed to לפניך:

> או נוכל לומר עוד שהזכיר על פניך כלומר אני אעביר כל טובי על פניך וממנו תתעלה שיחול האור על פניך והוא מעלת קרון פנים שזכה אליה מנקרת הצור וכמו שדרשו רז״ל.

Comment: Please translate or summarize when you can.

Comment: @DanF I didn't feel that was necessary here, but I clarified it in a different way.